# Trying to make Alarm Clock with Python, but it is not working

Tags: python, datetime

don't know where I got stuck. Seems fine for me.
Maybe the loop part doesen't work properly? Let me know if something is wrong.

```
import datetime
import time


year = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y"))
month = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%m"))
day = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d"))
hour = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%H"))
minute = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%M"))
second = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%S"))

setyear = int(input("Year"))
setmonth = int(input("Month"))
setday = int(input("Day"))
sethour = int(input("Hour"))
setminute = int(input("Minute"))
setsecond = int(input("Second"))

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    year = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y"))
    month = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%m"))
    day = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d"))
    hour = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%H"))
    minute = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%M"))
    second = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%S"))
    if year == setyear and month == setmonth and day == setday and hour == sethour and minute == setminute and second == setsecond:
        print("Alarm!")  
        break
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Comment: You should definitly ask a precise question, or add an explanation of what doesn't work, or a traceback.

Comment: Add the current output pls

Answer (score 0):

I believe because the types don't match and therefore values are interpretted differently.

For example:

input seconds "0" won't match to the seconds returned of "00", i removed your int()
conversions at the start and it now works. You just have to enter the proper digits:

```py
import time
import datetime


year = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y"))
month = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%m"))
day = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d"))
hour = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%H"))
minute = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%M"))
second = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%S"))


setyear = (input("Year"))
setmonth = (input("Month"))
setday = (input("Day"))
sethour = (input("Hour"))
setminute = (input("Minute"))
setsecond = (input("Second"))

while True:
    print(year,'-',month,'-',day,' ',hour,':',minute,':',second)

    time.sleep(1)
    year = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y"))
    month = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%m"))
    day = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%d"))
    hour = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%H"))
    minute = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%M"))
    second = (datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%S"))
    if year == setyear and month == setmonth and day == setday and hour == sethour and minute == setminute and second == setsecond:
        print("Alarm!")  
        break
    else:
        print("NO")
```

Output:

```
Year2020
Month11
Day12
Hour14
Minute12
Second00
2020 - 11 - 12   14 : 10 : 56
NO
2020 - 11 - 12   14 : 11 : 08
NO

....

2020 - 11 - 12   14 : 11 : 59
Alarm!
```

Comment: type mismatch indeed seems to be the issue; however I think the point is that the OP converts the `input` to int, while strftime returns a string. I'd suggest not to use strftime at all, only work with integers.